# Drupal 6 theme becomes corrupted after website backup

Tags: drupal, web, themes, corrupt, filezilla

I have found much to my grief that the website theme for a Drupal website, is not displaying properly after I downloaded a copy of the website with Filezilla (for backup purposes)

At the time I hadn't changed any of the files.
I've tried clearing the cache of the website, and nothing happens.

Please help! This is a business site for a client.

**Edit**
There were alot of errors, which were fixed when I pressed clear cache. It fixed the errors, but now the theme won't display correctly.

Some users also made some changes with admin privileges 3 hours before this happened, so I'm not really sure who or what is responsible.

To clarify:

1. The left sidebar seems display as a raw list without css
2. Top navigation seems to be mysteriously empty

Last known correct layout of site:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53535022/DrupalProblem/screenshot.png
Current layout of site:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53535022/DrupalProblem/WhatHappened.png

Comment: I hope what you are saying is that your styles are not being taken right..??

Comment: It just won't display properly.
I'm not an expert on Drupal, I was just asked to make a copy of the site.

Comment: is your specific theme showing in the themes listing..???

Comment: could you check if all your required css files are being loaded by inspecting it..??

Comment: Just update main post for additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether your `css` file is loaded on correct path or not...

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I wasn't able to resolve the issue, so they assigned the overseas team to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do try to debug your problem using the following

1.Try to check whether all the `css` files are being loaded.If it is not being loaded,then Do try to check the source of your problem. If it is through your `.info`   file,`template files` etc. Check that particular file..

2.Go to `admin > Settings > Performance`.See if you have enabled `css compression` ON.

3.Try resetting your theme to default theme and then try changing it to your needed theme.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I wasn't able to resolve the issue, so they assigned the overseas team to do it.